# FCM Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) Server key token expiry

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Can "Information on Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) server key token" ever expires or not?

I am using Token provided in firebase FCM Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) Server key. Can this token ever be expired or not?

If it expires then how to get refreshed server key again.